# Count always returns 1...but does it exist?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to check if a file name already exists in the "reviews" column within a particular category, before it's created. If it already exists, I want to add today's date to the name to make it a unique filename. I can't seem to find if it exists using count. When I echo $checkfile, it always returns 1, whether the file exists or not.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$list = service_category;
$php_file_name = $last."_".$first.".php";

$check = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT count(reviews) FROM table WHERE `category`='$list' AND `reviews`='$php_file_name'");

$checkfile = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($checkfile >= 1){
        $php_file_name = $last."_".$first.$today.".php";
        }
```

Comment: You are counting in your SQL statement which means your response will be ONE row. Then you're counting the rows. 

Remove your mysqli_num_rows and check the SQL result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `COUNT()` in your query you will always get one row returned even if only to tell you the count is zero. You need to check the value of `COUNT(reviews)` to get that value:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT count(reviews) AS `count` FROM myTable WHERE `category`='$list' AND `reviews`='$php_file_name'");
$check = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($check['count'] >= 1){
```

You'll notice that I gave `count(reviews)` an alias as it makes accessing that value easier in the PHP code.